# Exact difference between "Take up sth" and "Take to sth"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I just came across two phrasal verbs *"Take up sth" and "Take to sth"* and both mean to start.

Dug deeper, I found that "Take to" means *start often*, while "Take up" only means *to start*.

I was wondering, is it just the difference (often)? And with such a minor difference, how should I add these to my daily conversations? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The difference between the two is illustrated by the following examples with a similar context.

To **take up** something, means to start doing it frequently, e.g.

> “When I went to live in Switzerland I *took up* skiing, but I was never very good at it.”

(The first clause is similar to the example from [definition 4a in Merriam–Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20up).)

To **take to** something means to immediately or quickly become proficient at (and enjoy) some new thing, e.g. in the standard phrase:

> “He *took to* skiing [like a duck to water](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-to-sth-like-a-duck-to-water), and soon he was competing at national level.”

(The idea being that ducks do not need to be taught to swim, they do it naturally. Again — by chance — I find a similar skiing example in [Merriam–Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20to).)